# VBA VAL forcing a comma (,) instead of a period (.)

Tags: vba, autocad, autodesk

Basically, I am writting a small AutoCAD VBA that reads CSV files to run commands.

First, I put the csv into a string array (as it contains characters as well). One array position I need to use as a double for the command (as it requires it).

I though this would be a simple VAL() since it is supposed to keep the period regardlesss of my region.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    sfilename = "C:\Users\Patrick.Legault\OneDrive - Cima+\Projects\AutoCAD Styles\" & ComboBox1.Value & ".csv"
    Dim sLineFromFile As String
    Dim name As String
    Dim font As String
    Dim height As String
    Dim vlineItems() As String
    
    Open sfilename For Input As #1
    
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, sLineFromFile
        vlineItems = Split(sLineFromFile, ",")
        Call add_textstyle(vlineItems)
    Loop
        
    Close #1
End Sub

Sub add_textstyle(vlineItems() As String)
    '''Patrick Legault 2021-11-15
    '''This routine creates new textstyles with height
    
    Dim textStyle As AcadTextStyle
    Dim TextColl As AcadTextStyles
    Dim newfontstyle As String
    Dim fontpath As String
    Dim h_long As Double
    
    
    fontpath = "C:\Users\Patrick.Legault\OneDrive - Cima+\Projects\AutoCAD Styles\Fonts" '''to be changed
    
    Set TextColl = ThisDrawing.TextStyles '''get the textstyles from this drawing
    
    Set textStyle = TextColl.add(vlineItems(1)) '''add new textstyle
    textStyle.fontFile = fontpath & "\" & (vlineItems(2)) '''add new font style to textstyle
    h_long = CDbl(Val(vlineItems(3))) ''this returns the value with comma
    textStyle.height = (h_long)
    MsgBox h_long
    
End Sub
```

The csv in question is below:

```
Text,STD,Romans.shx,2.032,Main Text heght and style
Text,MD,Romans.shx,3.048,
Text,LG,Romans.shx,4.064,
Text,BOM TEXT,Romans.shx,1.5875,Text for Bill of Material
Text,BOLD,Bold.shx,5.08,"Custom FortisBC ""SHX file (Bold)"
Text,BOLDFILL,Boldfill.shx,5.08,"Custom FortisBC ""SHX"" file (Boldfill)"
Text,DIM,Romans.shx,0,"Dim used in Dimension Style ""Engineering"""
Text,NAMEPLATE,Romans.shx,6.35,"Use ""bigfont.shx"""
```

Comment: Would be useful to include a sample line from your input file.  What is the value of `vlineItems(3)` ?

Comment: Are you sure the issue isn’t with Msgbox and how it displays the value?

Comment: I added the CSV! Tim, that's what I thought at first so I tried to input it to autocad but since the decimal is a comma, it returns an error.

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?  Have you tried just `textStyle.height = Val(vlineItems(3))` ?

Comment: This is some wizardry! Putting val directly in like you mentionned works... Don't know why in detail but thank you so much! :)